# Jupyter method not allowed: why does this flag appear in my notebook menu?

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

I'm starting to learn Python and I'm currently following a MOOC using Jupyter, which seems to be a great tool. It's composed of several questions, each one requiring to write a piece of code.

I submit my code on a regulary basis so I know that this particular notebook works. But now I have an orange "Method not allowed" flag top right on my browser:

[image]

When I click on it it disappears for a while and then come back. All code chunks are executed without any error.

How could I get informations about how to solve this issue ?

**EDIT** :
It wasn't about the code written in the notebook. See answer below.

Thanks :)

Answer (score 7):

I finally figured out what it was for my case :

- This flag meant that some command from Jupyter menu somehow failed/was rejected (e.g. save & checkpoint at a moment my login session had expired)
- When using automatic commands (e.g. auto-save), it can appear randomly and be hard to understand
- It had no link with code in the notebook

This issue might have been caused by the fact I used Jupyter locally for personal purposes, at the same time I used MOOC's Jupyter.

**Reloading the page fixed the issue** but I lost some pieces of the code I wrote and I wasn't able to download the file before reloading (it failed too), so beware!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem (the orange 'method not allowed' message was appearing, and autosave and save were failing). Seems like it might be caused by an expired session as suggested by kdallaporta.

A solution that avoids reloading (as suggested by kdallaporta) and possible data loss is the following (this worked for me in a coursera notebook): log out and then log in from another window, and then open a new copy of the notebook (without closing the original notebook). The original notebook should work again without the problems above, and the new copy can be closed.